# Security sign from Phonegap App to external domain

Tags: security, cordova, code-access-security

I'm making an App with PhoneGap. I need to send some dates to an external domain that helps me to put it in a MySQL database.

I would like to create a sign that I send with my request to server, to check that these dates came from my own App. I don't want a third party to be able to make a request from outside to my external domain.

Comment: You're missing the question. Please try and elaborate what you need and how we can help you.

Comment: How can i make the request safety? I image something like the bank security key: one sign that i can use to be sure that my request is made from Phonegap to Php Script

Comment: Perhaps implement some sort of authentication modules, i.e. username and password when accessing the database?

Comment: @Corallino, does this have to work javascript onnly on the phonegap side, or is it ok to have native plugin (one for android, one for ihone, etc) under it?

Comment: @Gavriel I don't use native plugin, because i didn't find. I'm trying to make all by myself. Have you got some ideas?

Comment: Not yet, but also working on something and have similar problems. One thing I thought of was to require the user to log in, but I don't like that requirement, so trying to find a better solution. Obviously any solution (for example Th0rndike's) will not be 100% secure, but I hope to find something that stops the non-hackers at least

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you need a OTP system (one time password). I've never done something like this before, but i can give you some hints on how it works.

It works with pseudo-random number generators(PRNG) that are synchronized in the client and the server. To do this, you pass a secret seed to both your PRNG (client and server side) which will generate, after a pre-determined time lapse, a random number, which will be your password during that time lapse (before the new random number is created). Since both PRNG have the same seeds and algorithms, they both generate the same random number, allowing to match the password. I hope this helps.

Comment: This help me very well. Could you give me some interesting link about that? Really Tnx

Comment: I studied it in the university some time ago, and, unfortunately, i have no links or code to share with you, what I wrote was what i could remember about it. If you found the answer helpful, vote up! :)

Comment: Yes its really helpful. But i think that is not possible to realize with my technologies.